# Linking with -Wl,-E, what does it mean etc?

Tags: python, linux, g++, swig

I'm working on a project where we are using a Basler Pylon camera that comes with a CPP-API. Most of our other code, except picture taking, is written in Python so we use swig to wrap the take_image()-function from CPP.

These are our invocations of swig and g++:

```
swig -python -c++ frompytocpp.i

g++ -c -fpic  cppcamera.cpp frompytocpp_wrap.cxx
-I/opt/pylon/genicam/library/CPP/include -I/opt/pylon/include -DUSE_GIGE
-I/usr/include/python2.6

g++ -shared cppcamera.o frompytocpp_wrap.o -o _frompytocpp.so
-L/opt/pylon/lib64 -L/opt/pylon/lib -L/opt/pylon/genicam/bin/Linux64_x64
-L/opt/pylon/genicam/bin/Linux64_x64/GenApi/Generic -Wl,-E -lpylonbase
-lpylonutility
```

It compiles fine but during runtime when trying to create a camera object an exception is thrown that seems to relate to unresolved symbols. According to the camera API-manual, the flag -Wl,-E is critical "otherwise the linker will not know and match the pylon symbols correctly at runtime". I looked up the man-page for g++, realized that -Wl is used to pass options to the linker, but couldn't figure out what the -E option when passed to -Wl will do. Anyone?

The runtime problem only manifests itself when the picture taking function is called from python. So just standard compilation of cppcamera.cpp incorporating -Wl,-E works fine but something is not right/missing when we create the shared library used by the wrapper in python. Any suggestions on what might be missing in our g++-invocations?

Comment: Dude ? Paul ? I love you! I couldn't get the linker to create my executable because of this genicam. With some of your linker options I got it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can check the [help manual of `ld`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) (If `gcc` is set to use `ld` as the linker):

> #### `-E
> --export-dynamic
> --no-export-dynamic`
>
> **When creating a dynamically linked executable,** using the `-E` option or the `--export-dynamic` option **causes the linker to add all symbols to the dynamic symbol table.** The dynamic symbol table is the set of symbols which are visible from dynamic objects at run time.
>
> If you do not use either of these options (or use the `--no-export-dynamic` option to restore the default behavior), the dynamic symbol table will normally contain only those symbols which are referenced by some dynamic object mentioned in the link.
>
> If you use `dlopen` to load a dynamic object which needs to refer back to the symbols defined by the program, rather than some other dynamic object, then you will probably need to use this option when linking the program itself.
>
> You can also use the dynamic list to control what symbols should be added to the dynamic symbol table if the output format supports it. See the description of `--dynamic-list`.